# Button text lost when in landscape mode

Tags: android-layout

I have a simple screen with 4 buttons and their images:
[image]

and when I change it to landscape mode the images get cropped and the text is lost:
[image]

I am currently using a linear layout as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/rings" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top|fill_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/classesButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/menuitem_background"
            android:contentDescription="@string/title_activity_class_list"
            android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_classes"
            android:onClick="viewClasses"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:text="@string/classes"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/studentsButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/menuitem_background"
            android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_students"
            android:onClick="viewStudents"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:text="@string/students"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="bottom|fill_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/levelsButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/menuitem_background"
            android:contentDescription="@string/levels"
            android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_levels"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:onClick="viewLevels"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:text="@string/levels"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/skillsButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/menuitem_background"
            android:contentDescription="@string/skills"
            android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_skills"
            android:onClick="viewSkills"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:text="@string/skills"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

*Update* I changed the scale type to fitCenter and expected that to solve the issue but is has not.  I am truly puzzled why scaling doesn't resize the image to fit inside the layout when it seems like others have found it does scale images to fit on screens.

I have experimented with using a relative layout but can't find an easy way to have the 4 buttons fill the screen equally.

Thanks in advance, I've spent far too much time on this!

Comment: I know this isn't an answer, but for the sort of layout that you're using, you may just want to consider simply disabling landscape mode. It doesn't look like there is much need for it. It could save you a huge headache!

Comment: That's a reasonable idea Alex, unfortunately I've found that other screen sizes also have issues even in portrait mode so I have a bigger issue to solve that I think will be solved if I can get portrait and landscape working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the layout which results in a scaled image that is visible along with the corresponding text.  It took a lot of trial and error playing with Buttons, ImageButtons and ImageViews.  The layout I am now using contains child linear layouts that are clickable which contains a text and image view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/rings"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:gravity="top|fill_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/classesLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/menuitem_background"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="viewClasses"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/input_padding"
                android:text="@string/classes"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/classesIcon"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_classes"
                android:contentDescription="@string/classes"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/studentsLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/menuitem_background"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="viewStudents"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/input_padding"
                android:text="@string/students"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/studentsIcon"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_students"
                android:contentDescription="@string/students"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:gravity="bottom|fill_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/levelsLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/menuitem_background"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="viewLevels"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/input_padding"
                android:text="@string/levels"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/levelsButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_levels"
                android:contentDescription="@string/levels"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/skillsLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/menuitem_background"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="viewSkills"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/input_padding"
                android:text="@string/skills"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/skillsButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/skills"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_skills"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The resulting portrait and landscape renderings are:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could change the `Scale Type` of the images to see which option would work best for you (may not work due to the `fill_parent` & `Weight` of Images).

You could make `TextViews` and put the Text above the images instead of having the button already with text (personal preference).

If you would link me with the four images I could figure it out for you :)

Markus

Comment: Thanks Markus, I have tried changing the scale type to fitCenter and that seems to be helping.  Right now I'm experimenting with nesting linear layouts to contain a textView and a Button which is what I think you mention as your preference.  It seems promising.  I will post the result if it works.  I'd prefer to have a simpler layout and just use the text on buttons but I'm not sure how to get rid of the weight attributes and keep everything evenly spaced.  Perhaps a grid layout?